# Getting error while running an sql script in ADW

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Am getting an error that goes like this:
Insert values statement can contain only constant literal values or variable references.

these are the statements in which I am getting the errors:

```
INSERT INTO val.summary_numbers (metric_name, metric_val, dt_create) VALUES ('Total IP Enconters',
                                                                             (SELECT
                                                                                count(DISTINCT encounter_id)
                                                                              FROM prod.encounter
                                                                              WHERE encounter_type = 'Inpatient')

                                                                             ,
                                                                                (SELECT min(mod_loadidentifier)
                                                                                 FROM ccsm.stg_demographics_baseline)

                                                                             );


INSERT INTO val.summary_numbers (metric_name, metric_val, dt_create) VALUES ('Total 30d Readmits',
                                                                  (SELECT
                                                                     count(DISTINCT encounter_id)
                                                                   FROM prod.encounter_attr
                                                                   WHERE
                                                                     attr_name = 'day_30_readmit' AND attr_value = 1)

                                                                  ,
                                                                     (SELECT min(mod_loadidentifier)
                                                                      FROM ccsm.stg_demographics_baseline));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query like this:

```
insert into val.summary_numbers
select
        'Total IP Enconters',
        (select  count(distinct encounter_id)
         from    prod.encounter
         where   encounter_type = 'Inpatient'),
        (select  min(mod_loadidentifier)
         from    ccsm.stg_demographics_baseline)
```

Comment: When am using the above am getting parsing error near from statement

Comment: @DeadMan fixed a paren. Try again

Answer (score 0):

When using the ADW service, I would recommend that you consider using the [CTAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016) operation possibly combined with a [RENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/rename-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016). The RENAME is a metadata operation so it is fast and the CTAS is parallel where the INSERT INTO will be row by row.

You may still have a data related issue that can be hard to determine with out the create table statement.

Thanks